# Publishing packages for personal and commercial use

Tags: development-process, self-improvement, packages, nuget, npm

I have a pretty high level question for you and am looking for some different experiences and input. Does anyone publish their own private or public packages for their own personal convenience?

Obviously you encounter many instances of publishing packages in a general sense as a software developer. But I’m wondering if people do so as a way of organising and tracking their own personal self-contained pieces of work. For example, you might publish neat web components that you make in JS, or algorithms you write in C#, for potential future use. What happens if your neat web component was written as part of your job? Can you still package that up under your own name?

I’d appreciate any opinions on this topic! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In most jurisdictions, software that was written as part of your employment duties (aka your job) belongs to your employer. That means that you are not allowed to publish that software in any way without consent from your employer.

Even if the software is under an open-source license, as an employee you are acting as an agent of your employer and it is your employer who gets to decide if/when the software gets to be made public.

Comment: Are you aware of such arrangements? Are they commonplace? Fortunately, my company is happy to. Perhaps it’s harder in large organisations. Maybe you could “rewrite from memory”?